# The tense for something airing at the time of speaking

Tags: grammar

A speech is going on TV. There is a slide down there at the bottom of the screen to tell the viewers what is airing now. Which is the right pattern?

A. Speech being delivered to students of XYZ University

B. Speech delivered to students of XYZ University

Note: S+V+O pattern not to be used.

Comment: I don't think either would be wrong, but in my experience "ABC speaking at XYZ University" would be more likely, with a little sign in the corner of the screen saying LIVE if it was.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you say S+V+O cannot be used? If you're going to rule out the obvious correct answer, you should at least give a reason. This is like saying, "Who was the prime minister of Britain during World War 2? Note: Any answer that includes the name 'Churchill' will not be accepted."

If you are giving a complete sentence, you could say, "This speech is now being given to students of XYZ University." Or "This speech is currently being given ...", etc.

The context probably calls for a title or caption rather than a complete sentence. So to convey the idea I'd probably say "Speech to students of XYZ University". If I wanted to make clear that this was a live broadcast and not recorded, I might say "Live: Speech to students of XYZ University" or "Live broadcast of speech" etc. Or if you also rule out the word "live" for some arbitrary reason, maybe "Speech being given now ...".

Also in real life I'd probably identifier the speaker. Like, "Senator Jones speaking to students of XYZ University" or "Society for Good Stuff representative speaking to students of XYZ University".